# "Uncaught Error: In this configuration, Angular requires Zone.js" error when running angular2 app in production

Tags: iis, angular2-routing, angular5, angular-service-worker

I'm encountering error messages in the console when serving angular app in production.

I never got those errors before and besides playing around with the web.config to change the rewrite URLs, nothing has changed.

After building the app **locally** and serving it via my local IIS, the app loads and runs.

But when I try to reach it in production, I get:

**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < (index):1**

and also

**Uncaught Error: In this configuration, Angular requires Zone.js**

The app DOES RUN in production when I try to run it in incognito.

I'm using

```
"@angular/cli": "1.6.0-rc.1",
"zone.js": "^0.8.14"
"@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/service-worker": "^5.0.0",
```

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I can't explain why incognito works or why all of the sudden I got this error but upgrading to the latest cli 1.6.8 solved it

Comment: I had the same problem and this fixed it too.